# looking for good web site or book to learn HTML5+CSS3 styling by example

Tags: html, css

I learn best by example. I spend so much time searching, and can't find a book or a web site which does this: Show a finished web page (nothing too advanced, I am not trying to learn how Yahoo web page was coded!) just trying to learn how to do layouts, how to arrange items on the page, figures, columns, and such) and then show the code which generated this page.

I've seen many tutorials on how to make elements, make this and that. But that is not what I am looking for. I am looking to see sample layouts pages, and then see the code that was used to generate this layout.

I am just interested to learn how to layout a page. No javascript.

can someone please recommend either a book or a web site for this?

Again, I do not want tutorial on how to make divs and such. there is plenty of tutorials on the net. I want to learn by seeing the final page, then see the code which made the page.

Simple HTML5+CSS3 based layouts to help me learn.

Comment: what is the negative vote for?

Comment: for the kind of question you ask

Comment: Please read this before asking questions - [faq]...

Comment: Because this is not the type of site to ask these sorts of questions. Please see the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  This site is meant to help or guide you on specific problems, not learning how to do things. There are **plenty** of other resources for that.

Comment: Hi Steve, unfortunately recommendation questions are off-topic here, since they are only good for a limited duration.

Comment: voteS, not vote anymore. These are for not following community standards of asking a question.
Head First series is great for learning by example btw.

Comment: what is wrong with my question? This is a forum to get help from, is it not? I am simply asking for help.

Comment: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/‎) will be a good place to start from.

Comment: strange policy that someone can't ask for a recommendation to learn HTML in an HTML forum.

Comment: Steve - please read the [FAQ].  This is not a forum, nor an HTML specific site.  It's about providing concrete answers to programming problems.  Recommendations about books are subjective by nature, and will also provide answers that do not age well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If all you're looking for is to see the final outcome and then view the code, simply google "HTML5 web pages" then visit one, right-click and view source.

Also, this probably isn't the best place to be asking questions like this. SO is primarily for troubleshooting specific issues involving code that you have already written (or attempted to write.)